# Gradle Error: No method add() found for arguments

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-eclipse

So I'm adding a custom plugin to Gradle, specifically jmeter. https://github.com/kulya/jmeter-gradle-plugin

I thought everything worked, but now this error is occuring:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\rstraubel\Documents\DataCentral\build.gradle' line: 21

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'DataCentral'.
> Could not find method add() for arguments [jmeterEditor, class com.github.kulya.gradle.plugins.jmeter.JmeterRunGuiTask] on task set.
```

Line 21 is just where I call plugin: 'jmeter'
Everything else specified in the github has been done. Any ideas? Thanks

Edit: Full Build.gradle

```
buildscript {
ext {
    springBootVersion = '1.0.2.RELEASE'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone"}
    mavenLocal()
}
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    classpath("com.github.kulya:jmeter-gradle-plugin:1.3.1-2.6")
}
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'sonar-runner'
apply plugin: 'jmeter'

jar {
baseName = 'datacentral'
version =  '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}

repositories {
mavenCentral()
maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone" }
maven { url "http://m2.neo4j.org" }
}

dependencies {
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:${springBootVersion}"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-    mongodb:${springBootVersion}"
compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"
compile "org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb"
compile "org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:2.12.0-rc0"
compile "org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-webmvc"
testCompile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:${springBootVersion}"
 }


jmeterRun.configure {
jmeterTestFiles = [file("src/test/jmeter/TestCases.jmx")]
}

 sonarRunner {
sonarProperties {
    property "sonar.host.url", "http://hawkeye.control-tec.com:9000"
    property "sonar.jdbc.url", "jdbc:mysql://bluestreak.qualifier.control-tec.com:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8"
    property "sonar.jdbc.driverClassName", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    property "sonar.jdbc.username", "sonar"
    property "sonar.jdbc.password", "sonar-pass"

    property "sonar.projectKey", "com.controltec.incontrol.qualifier:Data-Central"
}
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
gradleVersion = '2.0'
}
```

Comment: Please show (at least) the full line 21 as-is. Which Gradle version are you using?

Comment: Edited with whole Build

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, the `jmeter` plugin hasn't been updated to support Gradle 2.0. You can verify by trying with 1.12.